# Git copy, merge with git chunk and preserve file history

Tags: git, svn, copy, red5

All, 
We use git for source control.

I have project use an open source RED5 project, I downloaded the source from the red5 chunk.

svn checkout from http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only

We made local changes to the source. Now there is a new major RED5 release, 200+ files has been updated. How do I make a copy of our current RED5 code and preserve the git history? so that I can do automatially merge of the RED5 code and only manually merge the conflict one.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain your problem little bit more? Hard to spot the exact problem you have.

Answer (score -1):

I would download all the source into another directory and create a diff/patch in that directory of all these 200+ file changes with something like `svn diff -r<LAST_CHECKOUT>:<NEW_CHECKOUT>`.

Then in your git repository I would apply that diff and handle all conflicts. Then just commit it as usual.

If you need it you could probably create a script that creates one diff for each commit in the svn repository.